# Permissions from Apple: photos, server etc

Tags: ios, objective-c

Our app has its own costume photo album that we are taking from the `assetsLibrary`.
This photos are sent to another user via server.
I have read that i need to get a user permission to get into their album, is it right? Isn't it happen automatically? seems there is some confusion about it. Right now I am not asking permission, but its pretty obvious because the user hit button to get into this album, and pick photos.

Second, when the app starts, we send lots of data to `server`, with `sockets-tcp` such as iPhone name, version, and some other const number from the software.

Does it require the user permission?
If the connection using `encryption ssl`, do we need apple's permission?

Comment: its not true. i am accessing the album and there is no such notification. my album is a costume album ,using the assetsLibrary .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you do need to get the users permission. Recently after the whole mess with congress and all the privacy breaches for collecting users info by some of the developers apple informed the developers that a notification for accessing personal info of the users is required. That is the reason you see any app that is trying to use the photo album or the contacts of the user are equipped with a pup up notification that the app is trying to use your photo album EtC ETC. it is being practiced widely. So I would say just plug in UI alert and ask the users permission. It is a good idea to stay safe and away from this legal stuff. That's my opinion.

To answer your second question, no you don't need apples' permission to send those data to your server.

Answer (score 1):

There are technical answers and there are legal answers.

For the legal side of this, you would do best to consult with a lawyer. There's a lot of potential privacy issues at stake, and a web of laws you may need to wade through, especially when you consider international issues (depending what App Store you're going to sell your app in). Plus how say the interaction of user in one place interacting with server in another place (e.g. crossing countries) could come into play. Yes, find a good lawyer.

If nothing else tho, consider the backlash that occurs when "tracking" of user information and behavior happens without letting the user know. When they find out (not if, when), do you wish to bring ill-will to your app and to your developer/company reputation? Often it's better to be up front and explicit. Allow the user to choose what to do, even if that means choosing to not use your app.

As for SSL, you don't need Apple's permission, but use of encryption CAN have implications upon store submission and distribution. This is covered extensively in Apple's store documentation. Check the FAQ's within iTunesConnect as well.